# wrap apart of image by touch in android

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to wrap image by hand like this app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tonuzaba.android
but I don't know how to start it. what I need to learn.

Comment: This post appears to be off-topic as per Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: So where should I ask question like this?

Comment: Feed your favourite search engine with key words, like android, programming, picture editing, morphing, animation, how to .... , ............

Comment: OK. I will delete it.

Comment: You do not have to, as this will be done by moderators or other magic creatures on stackoverflow, if they think the question is not approbiate for this site.

Comment: so what is the application of delete?

Answer (score 0):

for you have to learn ANIMATIONs in android.so go through tutorials which you are flexible for you..for your prasent requirement not exatly go throw this link and you can get suitable example with button onely not touch..if you wana tuch effect you have to implement them through clicklineseners..good luck..
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm